# How To make selenium try 2 xpath and get the correct one

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

**Hello I'am new to selenium - Python
The image in the message sometimes it be "messages-4" and sometimes it be "messages-3"
it changes with no reason( in the application ) so what ever i want selenium to try both of them to choose the correct one
is that possible? thanks,

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#messages-4 > div.container-1ov-mD > a > img")

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#messages-3 > div.container-1ov-mD > a > img")

i tried :

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#messages-4 > div.container-1ov-mD > a > img" or "#messages-3 > div.container-1ov-mD > a > img")**

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to implement this would be to use a try and except block like so:

```
try:
   driver.find_element_by_ccs_selector('#messages-3)
except Exception as e:
   print(e)
   driver.find_element_by_ccs_selector('#messages-4')
```

This means that first the driver will try to find message 3 and if message 3 does not exist the driver will try to find message 4

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two messages as shown below.

If you want to get the first matching element use <kbd>find_element_by_css_selector</kbd>, you want to get all matching elements then use <kbd>find_elements_by_css_selector</kbd>

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#messages-3,#messages-4 > div.container-1ov-mD > a > img")
```

**NOTE**: `,` is the `OR` operator in CSS.